# Test/Dummy SMTP server for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, smtp, selenium

I would like to install a Test/Dummy SMTP server on a Windows 2008 server (virtual box). I just want to test my web application on the machine it self so I don't need the mails to go out on the internet, but just to be written to disk (so that I can verify that the mail function was indeed called and the correct data was handed over to SMTP)

Can you recommend some tool. I guess starting your own SMTP server in python is an option. I am looking for a simple (ready to use) solution, targeted for tests systems. I will need to integrate it to automated tests (Selenium) at a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in SMTP service (*Server Manager → Features → Add Features → SMTP Server*). The mail will go to the drop directory (`C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop`).